# Mouse freezes but trackpad works

Tags: mouse, touchpad

My mouse constantly freezes/unfreezes at random. When it freezes it will not unfreeze on its own. I have tried several brands and models of wireless mice, some with bluetooth and some with a USB dongle, it makes no difference. When the mouse freezes I start using the track pad and then the mouse is again unfrozen after a bit. I have tried disabling the track pad while typing, it has no effect on mouse freezing. According to one suggestion I removed the .config/dconf/user file, the system recreated it upon reboot.


Host: Laptop AB
BIOS: INSYDE Corp. 3.17 (10/27/2022)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
DE: GNOME 42.5 (wayland) 
Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-43-generic
Shell: bash 5.1.16
WM: Mutter 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.7GHz 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
GPU Driver: i915 
Memory: 3.37 GiB / 15.41 GiB (21%)
Disk (/): 17G / 228G (8%)
Network: Wifi6 
Bluetooth: Intel Corp. AX210

Comment: FWIW, I just ran Vanilla OS on a stick and the same problem occurs there, too. Vanilla is an Ubuntu-derived OS, there might be some connection there, but perhaps it is the Framework architecture. I will ask around.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that the problem was a low battery in the mouse. After 30 minutes of continuous mousing and no stops that it was the battery.